# What does prefix "1:" in front of package version mean?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I have noticed that some packages have "1:" prefix in front of version number? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [epoch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/deb-version.5.html). It overrides the version in determining which of two packages is newer.

Comment: Broken link: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer